# Extract String Beetwen 2 Character in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want the string in column A to be extracted to each column, where the position of the string taken between "d /" and "/ search".

Based on the formula I made, it only extracts it in one column.

[image: My Table]

Comment: You should have a proper search around the net, try at least something yourself and post your issue on SO. A simple search on the net will give answers like [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1624-excel-extract-text-between-two-characters.html) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cell B2, you already have the formula as:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("d/",A2)+2,FIND("/search",A2)-FIND("d/",A2)-2)
```

You are really close, you only needed to add the starting position as an argument for the following formulas, so it will start searching after the previously found string as below.

In C2 add the following:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("d/",A2,FIND(B2,A2))+2,FIND("/search",A2)-FIND("d/",A2)-2)
```

And in D2 the following:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("d/",A2,FIND(C2,A2))+2,FIND("/search",A2)-FIND("d/",A2)-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 Excel it can be done with one formula:

```
=CONCAT(IF(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"d/","|/",COLUMN(A:A)),"/",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$100)*99,99))="|",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($2:$101)*99,99)),""))
```

this is an array formula, it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm certainly not going to retype all the sample data you left in an image for everyone to retype but try this in B2 then drag right and down,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way, Try this.

Apply the below formula in Cell B2

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," ")," ",REPT(" ",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," ")))), (2-1)*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," "))+1, LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," "))))&", "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," ")," ",REPT(" ",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," ")))), (4-1)*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," "))+1, LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," "))))&", "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," ")," ",REPT(" ",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," ")))), (6-1)*LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," "))+1, LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"d/"," "),"/search?"," "))))
```